# How is base container executed on Gitlab runner

Tags: docker, gitlab, containers, gitlab-ci-runner

I am working on a CI/CD pipeline which uses a containerised environment.

- On my laptop, everything thing is run within a centos container which contains all of my tools, while the code and configuration reside on a shared volume.
- Most of that shared volume gets pushed up to master when I submit.

  - But, for example, I exclude any python binaries from the virtual environment.
- That same container is used as my "base" container in Gitlab to execute some of my runner stages in order to

  - execute static lint testing of both the code and the ansible config
  - build the final product as a new image with ansible-bender

In order to distinguish the environments, I use a basic shell in the `entrypoint.sh` which is executed when the container comes up and in that shell, I used an environment variable which is managed by Gitlab: `CI_JOB_STAGE`. But the shell script doesn't seem to perform in the same way when I run the container locally as opposed to on the runner. Which is crazy, because that the whole point of containers isn't it?

- it's unclear at what point Gitlab mounts the share between the runner host and the container
- conditions testing the value `CI_JOB_STAGE` don't seem to work even though the values are shown when it printed out with and `echo`
- for some reason the entrypoint is executed both before **AND** after the stage executes

I am attaching gists for

- the entrypoint.sh script
- the output when the container is run locally

  - in this case, it see that the virtual env already exist by check for the existence of the activate binary, so that environment is simply activated
  - it then checks for the flask binary to see if it needs to install requirements
  - i know it's primitive, but this is just POC
- the output for the first stage of the runner

  - based on the shell script, it should not install the requirements because that is part of the stage commands anyway
  - I don't believe it actually does do so, because it goes by too quickly, but the message indicates that it went through the condition
  - `if [[ $CI_JOB_STAGE -eq "locally" ]] && ! test -f "./env/bin/flask"`

    - if the stage is local (false: we clearly see that stage is `lint_code`)
    - **AND**
    - flask is not present (well, it won't be, but it doesn't matter because the first half is already false)

The stages still run correctly, but I find this all very confusing. Does anyone have detailed knowledge of how these runners execute?

gists

- [the entrypoint.sh for the container](https://gist.github.com/mchassy/8cb9542cbf2b45c096c8e3b04fcc76b2)
- [output of entrypoint when the container runs locally on my laptop](https://gist.github.com/mchassy/b185fb838d92ccbe7bbed43f2ba81f16)
- [output of entrypoint and then of the stage commands and then strangely of the entrypoint **AGAIN**](https://gist.github.com/mchassy/d8086605dc6f820199115c2c5ed70c5e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitlab supports [number of executors](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/README.html) where each might behave slightly differently (executor might might mount custom volumes, forbid privileged containers)

The [general workflow](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#workflow) is:

1. Prepare: Create and start the services.
2. Pre-job: Clone, restore cache and download artifacts from previous stages. This is run on a special Docker image.
3. Job: User build. This is run on the user-provided Docker image.
4. Post-job: Create cache, upload artifacts to GitLab. This is run on a special Docker Image.

I would discourage from scripting in `entrypoint.sh`. try to rewrite it into `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - install
  - build
  - test

job 0:
  stage: .pre
  script: install some prerequisites 

job 1:
  stage: install
  script:
    - python3 -m venv env
    - source ./env/bin/activate
    - pip install -r ./dev/requirements.txt

job 2:
  stage: build
  script: make build

job 3:
  stage: test
  script: make test
```

It will make builds reproducible and easier to read. You might use [`.pre` and `.post` stage](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#pre-and-post), just make sure you're using Gitlab >= 12.4.

Comment: Will the pre and post job be executed on the container specified in the `default:` section? Maybe that's where I am messing up. Should I  leave the default image alone and specify a specific images for the different stages? This would explain why I see my `entrypoint.sh` being executed before and after each time.

Comment: @MarkChassy It's possible to use different images for each stage, but it gets more complicated. Unless you have some special requirement it's good idea to use well maintained image e.g. `python:3.7` and each run install dependent Pypi modules. Probably you will be changing dependent modules more frequently than Python version. Or you might have different `requirements.txt` per each stage.

Comment: Thanx @Tombart, I can't upvote yet. My account was on a job based email, and I lost all of my rep when I left the job ... that will teach me.